# Looping through elements using pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I need to loop through an array of 3 class elements and change the background of the second one that has the class using pure Javascript.

Here's code that I'm using but it's applying red to all 3 blocks regardless instead of only the second:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("newClass");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  if (x[1]) {
    x[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
  } else {
    x[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  }
}
```

Is there an easier way of doing this with pure Javascript.

I'd appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For-each over an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the solution to the problem

```js
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("newClass");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
      if (i ==1) {
          x[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
      }}
```

```html
<h1 class="newClass">hello world</h1>
<h1 class="newClass">hello world</h1>
<h1 class="newClass">hello world</h1>
<h1 class="newClass">hello world</h1>
<h1 class="newClass">hello world</h1>
<h1 class="newClass">hello world</h1>
<h1 class="newClass">hello world</h1>
<h1 class="newClass">hello world</h1>
<h1 class="newClass">hello world</h1>
```

and I also think this is a problem solving

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("newClass");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }
document.getElementsByClassName("newClass")[1].
   style.backgroundColor = "red"
```

```html
<h1 class="newClass">hello world</h1>
<h1 class="newClass">hello world</h1>
<h1 class="newClass">hello world</h1>
<h1 class="newClass">hello world</h1>
<h1 class="newClass">hello world</h1>
<h1 class="newClass">hello world</h1>
<h1 class="newClass">hello world</h1>
<h1 class="newClass">hello world</h1>
<h1 class="newClass">hello world</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer ES6:

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('newClass');
if (elements) {
  // color them all yellow
  elements.map(element => element.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow');
  // color the second element red
  if (elements[1]) elements[1].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether `i == 1`, not `x[1]`:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("newClass");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (i == 1) {
        x[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    } else { 
        x[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }
}
```

Comment: and, for every *other* one, you can use `if( i % 2 === 0 )`

Comment: Yes @StevenStark, but the OP only wants the *second* one.

Comment: yes, I'm just adding additional information as this is a very common thing to do next.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The yellow applies for background to all 3 classes. It seems the condition isn't working. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @new_coder the condition is correct. if it's not working, I'd look into your HTML and CSS to debug where it's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you need but in the question you just asked about changing the background color of the second element, so this should be enough. Let me know if this isn't what you're looking for.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("newClass")[1].style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop over the elements with that class you can do this

```
let x = document.getElementsByClassName("newClass");
[...x].forEach((item, i) => {
  if (i == 1) {
    item.style.background = "red";
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

// typeof x is object becareful

```js
let x = document.getElementsByClassName("newClass");
[...x].forEach((item, i) => {
    item.style.background = "yellow";
});
[...x][1].style.background="red";
```

```html
<h1 class="newClass">hello world</h1>
<h1 class="newClass">hello world</h1>
<h1 class="newClass">hello world</h1>
<h1 class="newClass">hello world</h1>
<h1 class="newClass">hello world</h1>
<h1 class="newClass">hello world</h1>
```